# Linkedin API wont ger profile data

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

Im using linkedin's JS api to get some user profile information. I have this in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key: xxxxx
authorize: false
onload: getProfileData
</script>
```

And this is what i am using to pull the data:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

function getProfileData(){
IN.API.Profile("me").fields(["firstName","lastName","headline","summary"]) .result(function(result) {
   alert JSON.stringify(result)) 
}
</script>
```

However (checking through firebug) I do not what i asked it for. Instead it does a get request for standard information:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people::(~):(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url)
```

Anyone know what this issue could be or how to fix? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are a number of errors in your code:

First, using `authorize: false` with an onLoad callback will not work, as authorize: false requires the user to manually 'SignIn' for every page load, and the onLoad call takes that option out of their hands. Secondly, you have `onload` in the bootstrap section, it should be `onLoad`. The following will fix both of these:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: xxxxx
  authorize: true
  onLoad: getProfileData
</script>
```

Additionally, you are missing a number of brackets, etc in the actual worker code - the following should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function getProfileData() {
    IN.API.Profile("me")
      .fields(["firstName", "lastName", "headline", "summary"])
      .result(function(result) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
      });
  }
</script>
```

Keep in mind, if you would like to get anything more than the [basic fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#profile), you will need to [ask for permission from the user](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication#granting).

Comment: Thanks for the help. for some reason its the function not firing. Tried your code with no avail. Odd.

Comment: Did you ensure that onLoad has a capital L? The code I posted verbatim works for me.

Comment: weird. Yeah it is. for some reason i went in and renamed the function onLoad has and it worked. Thanks paul. my onLoad function became "paultoldmeso" and now its running fine

Comment: Follow-up question: If the user is not logged in, does the Profile API call fail silently? Can I somehow catch that?